# Copying from one cell to another cell on a different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, cell

I'm new to Visual Basic on Excel and I've been struggling trying to copy one cell to another on a different sheet. For example, if `Sheet1` has the following:

```
Animal    Owner
Dog       John
Cat       Gabe
```

And `Sheet2` is simply blank, assuming `Animal` and `Owner` are in different columns and are in `columns A` and `B` respectively, I just wanted to copy `Dog` into A2 (Animal is in cell A1) onto sheet two, for example.

I tried to look things up online and tried:

```
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

dataSheet.Range("A2").Copy DestinationSheet.Range("A2")
```

But I keep getting an error saying that:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

I just want to copy from one cell to another onto a different worksheet. If anyone has any idea to do so, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim x as integer
x = 1
do until Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Value = ""
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Value
x = x + 1
Loop
```

I dont know how well this works for moving formulas and formatting around, but it works fine for values.

Comment: If I wanted to move strings around, would i just dim x as string and it would work the same?

Comment: in this case, x is just a counter- it designates the row.

Comment: Ah okay. I'll try this out right now and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: Hm, I stopped the code and it seems to work, but it isn't copying onto the new sheet. Do you know how to make it appear in the new sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure why- I realize you weren't looking for a loop.  So, to set the value of a cell on the active sheet, just Range("A1").Value = something.  If you want to specify a sheet, just start that statement with Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A1").Value instead.  So, to make the value of A1 on Sheet 2 = A1 on Sheet 1, type Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value.  That will work in moving the value.

Comment: If you would like another way to do the same but avoiding a loop you can give my answer a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that gets rid of the need for a loop, this will needs to more reliable and faster execution:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim lngSh1LastARow As Long

'Get last row in Sheet1 Column A
lngSh1LastARow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Select the same range but on sheet 2
With Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1:A" & lngSh1LastARow)

    'Set sheet2's A column = to Sheet 1 A column
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!RC"

    'Remove all formulas from Sheet2 column A and retain just the value
    'Note: This step is optional If sheet1 Column A has formulas and you would
    'like to retain those formulas on sheet2 as well simply delete or 
    'Comment out the next line
    .Value = .Value

End With

End Sub
```